# Could you explain this simple image slider code line by line?

Tags: javascript, carousel

Are you able explain this simple image slider code line by line?

I'm particularly interested in where the n and no values come from in currentSlide(no) + plusSlides(n).

```
var slideIndex = 0;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
var interval;
var pauseButton = document.getElementById("pause");

showSlides();
playSlideshow();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
// Manual control 
function currentSlide(no) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex = no;
  slides[no - 1].style.display = "block";
}

function plusSlides(n) {
  var newslideIndex = slideIndex + n;
  if (newslideIndex < 6 && newslideIndex > 0) {
    currentSlide(newslideIndex);
  }
}
```

Edited to add rest of the code.

```
// Pause

var playing = true;

function pauseSlideshow() {
  var pauseButton = document.getElementById("pause");
  pauseButton.innerHTML = "&#9656;";
  playing = false;
  clearInterval(interval);
}

function playSlideshow() {
  pauseButton.innerHTML = "&#x23F8;";
  playing = true;
  interval = setInterval(showSlides, 5000);
}

pauseButton.onclick = function () {
  if (playing) {
    pauseSlideshow();
  } else {
    playSlideshow();
  }
};
```

As per the comments, I have added additional code.

Comment: Can you please include `playSlideshow` function in your code above as well?

Comment: You didn't show the whole code. `plusSlides` function is never called in your example, and `playSlideshow` is never defined in it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question about specific code fragment not likely to be of general interest.

Comment: As a sidenote, it looks there's a bug here, introduced by mixing up `no` (starting from 1) and `index` (0-based) in `currentSlide` function.

Comment: Apologies, I have now aded the rest of the code @raina77ow

Comment: I have now included playSlideshow, apologies @Tethys0

Comment: @StasM An image slider or carousel isn't of general interest? I beg to differ. I think down voting is a bit uncalled for when someone is trying to learn how a general carousel slider works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Yes, can do!

The first function `showSlides` is called. It first makes every element with the `mySlides` class invisible (basically hides all your slides). Then it increments the slide index and checks to see if the index is over the total amount of slides so it can start from the beginning again. Finally it shows the slide that the index is referring to.

The `currentSlide` function sets the active slide to the index provided in the `no` argument. First it hides all the slides and then sets the new slide index to what `no` is and then shows that slide.

Finally `plusSlides` goes forward (or backwards if using a negative number) `n` slides. The `if` statement checks if the index is between 1 and 5. If it is the slide that corresponds with the new index is shown.

#### A few notes

- `for loops` can be written without a variable declaration preceding it like this

```js
for(let x = 0; x < 100; x++){
    console.log(x);
}
```

- In your `plusSides` function, you check for a specific range, but you could base it off of the amount of slides with `slides.length` like in `showSlides`. Also, I would recommend making sure that if the index does happen to fall out of this range to set the index to a default value.

```js
if (newslideIndex < slides.length && newslideIndex > 0) {
    currentSlide(newslideIndex);
} else {
    currentSlide(1);
}
```

That is all!

Comment: Appreciated the detailed response. Where does the no argument in currentSlide get it's index or value from?

Comment: When the function is called in `plusSlides` it passes an argument to the `currentSlide` (your `no` argument) which is the new index that you supposedly want to be set.